# stringResource() causing recompose of composition

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose

I am beginner at jetpack compose. I was debugging recomposition but suddenly I saw a unusual recomposition in **Header** compose function when app start.
I find out the reason or culprit for the recomposition that I used in **Header** compose function to get string text by stringResource().. If I use context.getString() or hardcode string value instead of stringResource() then I got no recomposition.

This code when showing the recomposition

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    Header()
}

@Composable
fun Header() {
   Text(
    text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name)
   )
}
```

But If I use these codes No more recomposition. But why?

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    Header()
}

@Composable
fun Header() {
   val context = LocalContext.current
   Text(
    text = context.getString(R.string.app_name)
   )
}
```

So what can I do for get rid of recomposition when using stringResource() into compose functions

Comment: I also found stringResource causes two compositions.  Unfortunately, Google says this is intended and won't fix it https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/239060887#comment3

Answer (score 0):

if you have the value saved in the `res/values/strings.xml` file then using compose the only thing you will need to do is calling the `stringResource(R.string.app_name)`. Jetpack Compose handles getting the resource on its own. you wont even need to get it from your `Context`.
see [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/resources) for docs on resource.

that should not cause recomposing every time but if it does it is always a good practice to save your values inside of a remember so that it knows not to recompose every time. the problem might be from a different part of your code.

Comment: I did remove the stringResource() and found no recomposing, I thing that might be a bug from compose!

Answer (score -1):

First of all, this behavior shouldn't be happening, I recommend creating a clean project and trying again.

But... to avoid recomposing inside Composable, the `Effect` API would be useful:

```
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var appName = ""
        
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        appName = context.getString(R.string.app_name)
    }
    Text(
        text = appName
    )
```

The codes inside the `LaunchedEffect` block are only executed once, even if the recomposition happens.
[Documentaion of api Side Effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects)

Comment: it could be a bug?